# Using .unless in express.js to avoid jsonwebtoken verification for a couple of routes

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I don't want jwt to verify the token for login and register request. Once the user is loggedIn a token is created using jwt.sign() after that to verify every request, I am using jwt.verify()
I think there is a way to use .unless with app.use(). I did install express-unless but it still doesn't seem to run.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    // console.log(req.body);
    var token=req.body.authtoken || req.query.authtoken || req.headers['authtoken'] ||req.headers.authorization;
    console.log(token);
 jwt.verify(token,'my-secret-key',function(err,decoded){
    if(err){
    res.send({
        err:true,
        msg:'Invalid Request'
    });
}else{
    req.decoded=decoded;
    next();
}`enter code here`
})

}).unless({path:['/register','/login']});
```

Comment: What happens when you add `/` add the end of your `path` routes like, `.unless({path:['/register/','/login/']});` ?

Comment: It keeps on showing this error.TypeError: app.use(...).unless is not a function. I did var unless = require('express-unless'); then I am using it.